# how to remove "&#2346;" from html code by using jsoup while extract text

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

when i am using this program 
that "content=content.replaceAll("&.*?;","");" syntax is not work to remove "&#____;" from extracted text, all word like "&#____;" shown as question "?" mark . tell me how do i remove "&#____;" from text..

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

class JavaSoup1
{
 public static void main(String []args)throws Exception 
 {
       Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.iitbhu.ac.in/").get();

       String content=doc.text();

       content=content.replaceAll("&.*?;","");

       System.out.println(content);
 }
}
```

Comment: repalceAll takes a regex as first param, since you are using & and dot you have to escape it for it to work. For the word showing as ? make sure you read the URL using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Try `.replaceAll("&#_+;", "")`. There is no need escaping `&`, nor `#`.

Comment: `text()` method should handle converting `&#XXXX;` into proper character from Unicode Table for you. Why would you want to print them as `?` ? Your question looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Or try `.replaceAll("\\x{2346}+", "")`.

Comment: i do not want to print as ? that is encoded itself as ? mark after extraction .

Comment: just i want to remove them

Comment: here no underscore are present instead of underscore numeric value is present with &#

Comment: after extraction &#5632; is converted as ? in extracted text

Comment: just i want to remove &#7928; from my  extracted text

Comment: try doc.toString() instead

Comment: then do the suggestions of the people above